# How to avoid subqueries inside SELECT when using XMLTABLE()?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a function that returns XML clob. It takes address as an input. Returned XML contains latitude, longtitude, street name, undeground station and all those useful things.

Problem is that I can't connect any table that has address column to XMLTABLE using joins. Because the address is a just a paramentr of the function:

```
-- This is not going to work and will cause ORA-00904
  SELECT t.address, ad.latitude, ad.longitude, etc
    FROM   TABLE_that_has_address_in_it,
           (SELECT a.address, a.latitude, a.longitude, a.loc_quality
            FROM   xmltable('/SuggestResponse/suggestions' passing xmltype(function_that_returns_xml(t.address)) columns
                            address VARCHAR2(300) PATH 'value', latitude VARCHAR2(50) path 'data/geo_lat', longitude VARCHAR2(50) path
                             'data/geo_lon', loc_quality VARCHAR2(2) path 'data/qc_geo') a) ad
```

What I can do is make a lot of subqueries inside SELECT statement with XMLTYPE, for example. But that doesn't sound great since Oracle will call the same function and get the same xml clob X times.

It feels like that there is a way to do it using one XML table. What do you thing?

UPD:
Here is how I would write this query calling this function and getting heavy clob many times. It seems so inefficiently to call the same function with the same paramentr that return really heavy xml:

```
SELECT t.address,
       (SELECT address
        FROM   xmltable('/SuggestResponse/suggestions' passing xmltype(function_that_returns_xml(t.address))
                        columns address VARCHAR2(300) PATH 'value')) AS address,
       (SELECT latitude
        FROM   xmltable('/SuggestResponse/suggestions' passing xmltype(function_that_returns_xml(t.address))
                        columns latitude VARCHAR2(300) PATH 'data/geo_lat')),
       (SELECT longitude
        FROM   xmltable('/SuggestResponse/suggestions' passing xmltype(function_that_returns_xml(t.address))
                        columns longitude VARCHAR2(300) PATH 'data/geo_lon'))
FROM   TABLE_that_has_address_in_it t
```

Or

```
SELECT t.address, XMLTYPE(function_that_returns_xml(t.address)).extract('SuggestResponse/suggestions/data/geo_lat/text()'  , ''  )
       .getStringVal(),
       XMLTYPE(function_that_returns_xml(t.address)).extract('SuggestResponse/suggestions/data/geo_lon/text()'  , ''  )
       .getStringVal(),
       XMLTYPE(function_that_returns_xml(t.address)).extract('SuggestResponse/suggestions/value/text()'  , ''  )
       .getStringVal()
FROM   TABLE_that_has_address_in_it t
```

Comment: Please post your query as text, not as an image.

Comment: Please post a [MRE] including an example of your function, the DDL statements for a minimal example of your table, DML statements for some sample data that replicates the issue, your SQL query (as text, not an image) and your expected output. This will make it a lot clearer what you expect.

Comment: You also haven't actually said what the problem is - I assume you're getting "ORA-00904: "T"."ADDRESS": invalid identifier" ? Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And, also, post the error message your query is giving.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gets "ORA-00904: "T"."ADDRESS": invalid identifier" because the reference to `t.address` is nested two levels down. That is nothing to do with XML or XMLTable, that's a normal (if sometimes frustrating) restriction. Fortunately, the subquery isn't necessary.

You can use a cross join directory to the XMLTable call rather than via a subquery; something like:

```
select t.some_col, x.latitiude, x.longitude
from table_that_has_address_in_it t -- AS is not allowed in table aliases
cross join xmltable (
  '/SuggestResponse/suggestions'
  passing xmltype(function_that_returns_xml(t.address))
  columns latitiude number path 'data/geo_lat',
    longitude number path 'data/geo_lon'
) x
```

or with  legacy syntax, just because that is what you originally had (but there is no reason not to use the 'modern' syntax):

```
select t.some_col, x.latitiude, x.longitude
from table_that_has_address_in_it t,
xmltable (
  '/SuggestResponse/suggestions'
  passing xmltype(function_that_returns_xml(t.address))
  columns latitiude number path 'data/geo_lat',
    longitude number path 'data/geo_lon'
) x
```

On one level that is just simplifying your code, by removing the redundant subquery. On the face of it there is no functional difference. But that simplification removes the nested reference to the outer table, resolving the ORA-00904 in the process.

Comment: Is that not functionally the same query as the OP's, as they are both correlated to the `t` alias in the function call? Just the OP's uses the legacy Oracle comma joins and this one uses modern ANSI joins.

Comment: Sort of, in that it just avoids the subquery, which was the question title. But with the subquery it'll get `ORA-00904: "T"."ADDRESS": invalid identifier` because the `t` is two levels down. Of course, it would help if the question actually said that was the issue *8-)

Comment: And of course I've end up up breaking the don't-answer-unclear-questions rule; I was just simplifying originally, not having spotted instantly that it would actually error. I'll leave this up anyway for now as it would fix that problem, but... feels dirty...

Comment: I'm really sorry for making everything unclear. I've updated my question.

Comment: @AlexPoole I've just run your query and it works perfectly. Unfortunately, I haven't heard of cross joins before. Now I know how to use it. Thank you for that!

Comment: You were using a cross-join before, but using legacy syntax, as MTO mentioned, with a comma between each table (or between tables and inline views). This approach still works with old syntax, it's just better to be explicit and use modern syntax. The important bit is to not have the unnecessary subquery.